# Error when trying to connect a component that returns an array of nodes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a functional component that takes an array of data and maps it to an array of nodes (abbreviated code):

```
const TemplateLinkCardList = ({ templates }: TemplateLinkCardListProps ) => {

    const cardFromData = (templateData: TemplateData) => {
        return (
            <TemplateCard {...templateData} />
        )
    }   

    return templates.map(cardFromData)
}
```

but when I try connecting it to redux:

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(TemplateLinkCardList)
```

I get an error:

> Error:(21, 3) TS2345: Argument of type '({ templates, toggleFavourited, onClickSideEffects, cardVariant, color, }: TemplateLinkCardListProps) => JSX.Element[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType'.
>
> > Type '({ templates, toggleFavourited, onClickSideEffects, cardVariant, color, }: TemplateLinkCardListProps) => JSX.Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.
> >
> > > Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component)>': type, props, key

Wrapping the returned inside a fragment resolves the error:
`<>{return templates.map(cardFromData)}</>` instead of `return templates.map(cardFromData)`

What's wrong with my original code? How do I connect a component that returns an array of nodes?

Answer (score 0):

In react return should be wrapped inside a single tag only and map creates multiple siblings without a parent, hence the error.

Fragments

A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

Check out this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-fast-x95ec

I use map here.
When you don't wrap it inside a div, it doesn't work,
Try the other case as well.

Comment: Map doesn't create multiple siblings without a parent, it returns a single array.   
  
That's the difference between `array.map()` and `...array.map()`.
  
I understand that the latter wouldn't work for the reasons you pointed out.  But returning arrays works just fine (even TypeScript was fine with it until i tried to connect the component).

Comment: Well technically it does 'create multiple siblings without a parent', but doesn't return them like that

Comment: Check out  the sandbox

Comment: If it works for you with Typescript, I am guessing connect being imported from 'react-redux' expects a single wrapping tag in the return value.

Comment: Well, the sandbox is broken because you use invalid syntax! Just remove the curly brackets and it works just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-hooks-z82h5

Comment: And yes, it's probably something about connect not expecting an array-returning component. I'd love to somehow get it to work, but guess I'm out of luck.